# Error 404 on Facebook Callback Url in Azure Bot

Tags: facebook, azure, botframework, messenger

I've created a bot with Bot Framework hosted in Microsoft Azure and It worked fine until yesterday.
From that moment when the bot tries to call the RootDialog, It generates an exception

```
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog());
```

The exception message is

```
Bad Request 
in Microsoft.Bot.Connector.MicrosoftAppCredentials.<RefreshTokenAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
```

If I call my callback url I get an error 404.
Any helps is appreciated.
Thanks

**UPDATE**

Now, It works again. I wrote to Azure in order to understand why I didn't work for two days.

Comment: There was a temporary issue with Azure AAD yesterday that caused bot token issues.  This has since been resolved.  Please follow here for updates: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4432

Comment: @EricDahlvang thank you!